# Switch to ground using transistor

Tags: transistors, ground, automotive

I am building an AVR-based diagnostic device for my old Mitsubishi car.

To perform diagnostics you must short pin 1 (diag) with pin 4 (ground) on the car diagnostics connector to start a session; no problem with a paper clip.

**But do I do this with a transistor controlled by an AVR output pin?**

A pseudo circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY6fh1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Just add a series resistor between the transistor base and AVR pin. Between 1K-5K should do it.

Comment: This will probably work but you have to limit the current into the base of that NPN. So add a resistor (any value between 1 k ohm and 10 kohm will do) between the base of the NPN and the AVR output.

Comment: As others said, add a 10k resistor in series with the base of Q1

Comment: Also, recommend a 47K pull-down on I/O pin (not gate/base) for after power-up, while MCU is in reset and I/O pin is still configured as an input, until software sets it as output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend that you use an N-Channel MOSFET instead, with a logic level gate threshold.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyZ3fo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But, if you wish to use an NPN BJT, as you show, then add a 1 kOhm resistor between the AVR and the base of the transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f12lgO.png)</sup>

Comment: *logic level NMOS. This is where a BJT might win out because all BJTs will work here but most NMOS won't.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: You really should add a MOSFET series resistor for gate capacitance, suggest 1K. This stops any load transients being coupled back to the MCU. Also limits peak charge/discharge current through I/O pin when switched. Also, recommend a 47K pull-down on I/O pin (not gate/base) for after power-up, while MCU is in reset and I/O pin is still configured as an input, until software sets it as output.

Answer (score 13):

> *I am building AVR based diagnostic device for my old Mitsubishi car*

I'm going to recommend a photo-MOSFET and some may say that this is over the top but, **automotive jobs** can be prone to problems of earthing (mainly avoiding multiple earths and thus avoiding unholy currents passing down wires that are not expecting unholy currents). So, I recommend a photo-MOSFET like this device: -

[image]

It's basically an optical replacement for a standard mechanical relay and has an on resistance of 2 Ω, an open circuit maximum voltage of 200 volts (will not be bothered by automotive load dumps) and, can conduct 0.7 amps. It's also bidirectional on the output so, if you get it back to front, it will still work: -

[image]

It only needs 3 mA input current to activate this device too but, of course you'll need a series resistor from your IO line.

It also costs virtually nothing in [Mouser](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TLP3558AF?qs=r5DSvlrkXmLolvaAE4UvXg%3D%3D) for your peace of mind: -

[image]

And they have plenty in stock with plenty of [alternatives](https://www.mouser.co.uk/c/optoelectronics/optocouplers-photocouplers/mosfet-output-optocouplers/?package%20%2F%20case=DIP-4%7E%7EDIP-4%20Wide&rp=optoelectronics%2Foptocouplers-photocouplers%2Fmosfet-output-optocouplers%7C%7EPackage%20%2F%20Case).

Of course, if you are willing to have your AVR connected to automotive ground in multiple places then be prepared for tears and anguish. Isolation is an excellent way to overcome most automotive sins.

> *But do I do this with a transistor controlled by an AVR output pin?*

Yes you can but, do it with a MOSFET and use optical isolation methods (as per the above) to avoid multiple connections to automotive ground.

Comment: While this does not directly answer OP question (although one can argue that FETs in isolator _are_ technically transistors), this is certainly the best option of all answers and comments. Considering the sensitivity of CMOS and wild electrical noise and ESD in and around cars there is no such thing as "too much protection".

Comment: @Maple you are quite correct; I didn't address the question explicitly so, I've added that bit at the end.

Comment: Good grip, @Andyaka  It may be worth to discuss about the controller (AVR) side ground, related to the vehicle ground.

Comment: @jay - he needs to be careful about that of course and, I'd definitely be considering using an isolated dc converter to avoid that through-going power connection to the AVR. But, that's another question as I see it. You can take a horse to water etc..

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, upvote your answer.

Comment: @user2120666 were the "subtleties" of automotive ground a bit difficult to take on board?

Comment: No but i dont see reason to use optocoupler. Because AVR ground is already connected with car ground, dc convertor too.

Comment: @user2120666 so your are perfectly content unrelated automotive ground currents won't flow from the grounding point you have close to the transistor in your question (on the diagnostic connector) via the AVR and back to ground at the other car ground? And, if you haven't got a local ground point back to the AVR for your gate/base drive signal, how can you be sure you won't get serious glitches between the two ground on your vehicle that might be turning on and off the transistor every 10 seconds or more when the engine is running....

Comment: ... Even worse, within a a short period of time, the ground bounce problems (that occur on any vehicle) might destroy the transistor or even your AVR. Have you ever heard of star-pointed wiring as a means of overcoming these issues. If not, good luck; I've tried my best to advise you but sometimes it takes real problems for disbelief to turn into acknowledgement.

Comment: Sorry. I honestly don't understand your comments. My knowledge of this is very poor and sure you have better expertise. But everything was working almost 2 years using grounding pin 1 with dip switch. Now I try transistor, because i have at home 500 BC548.

Comment: The very best of luck.

Comment: @user2120666 What is called "ground" on a car is not the same voltage everywhere - when things like windscreen wipers or a heated screen, or anything else really, are switched on, there will be a difference in the ground between any two places. Those two places could be the ground connection of the transistor and the ground connection of the AVR, and the difference could easily be enough to break them. So you need to either isolate the transistor or make sure to use only one ground wire to the car for *both* the transistor and the AVR.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Thanks for explanation, now I better understand this. Sure I use only one ground for whole board.

Comment: @user2120666 ah but, one ground isn't sufficient when you are directly driving a non isolated transistor because, without the local ground (a 2nd ground) at the transistor, there'll be so much noise on the chassis that the transistor will be switching on and off maybe once per second, minute, day, week etc.. Now do you see the problem?